# Swift Firebase viewcontroller only for specific user

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my app I have to validate user generated content, to do that I saw that with the panel of Firebase is not a fast thing, so I searched and I found Firebase FireAdmin, but it's not free and what I want is only change a value of approvation from not to yes (after have seeing content).

It's a good idea to make a viewcontroller hide for all exept from me by checking firauth property of Firebase?

```swift
 let userID : String = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!

 if userID == myid... { show view controller...
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: Are you asking if you should include admin functionality via a view in your app and only display that view if you (the admin) are using the app?

Comment: yes it is what i thinked

Comment: No way to answer that because it depends on your use case. Adding an admin view controller isn't a big deal as long as it's kept simple. However, it does make the app less secure from a decompiling perspective. This is an opinion question which is not really appropriate for this forum. Please take some time and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: do you think that is better if i make a little new app that will not be pubblished for making that change?

Comment: It depends on your use case. Implementing a separate app that only you have access to would be more secure but a larger code base - if you make a change then two apps may need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not a good idea. This value can be changed or the controller can be access if your code is usafe. The application will be heavier for a controller that will not be used by users.

You have to build an admin interface if you don't want to pay for FirebaseAdmin.

In function of what you are looking for, you can also have a look at Firebase Database where you can read and edit values.